# How does the --root option of gdebi work?

Tags: package-management, gdebi

I'm trying to install a local `.deb` file and all it's dependencies from local `.deb` files, too.

I want to use `gdebi` and saw, that it has a `--root` option.

```
   --root=ROOTDIR
          Use alternative root dir.
```

But I am not quite sure, how this option works.

Does `ROOTDIR` need to be a chroot, or can it be any folder? When trying to install the `firefox` `.deb` file I get a different error message, when having and not having the `--root` option.

I was searching online for a more specific explanation on what that option does, but could not find it.

My use case is, installing a package and their dependencies from local `.deb` files into a chroot.